# full-text property change on column

Tags: sql-server

i'm trying to modify a property of a column (in sql server 2008 r2) which is of xml data type. I want set (Is full-text indexed) to yes, but after I do this and try to save changes, i get an error:

> 'Abc' table
>   - Unable to modify table.   Column: B is not full-text
>   searchable.

Column B is not the column I'm modyfing, but it's content is based on the modified xml column (it takes a value from one element in xml). Weird thing is that column B is full-text indexed (in table designer). Any ideas why i cannot apply changes to the xml column?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Abc] ADD ([Xml_Column_Name])
```

this works